# why can't i call a subclass method from a superclass object

Tags: java

```
Consider below two classes

class Parent {
public void parentMethod(){
System.out.println("inside parentMethod");
}
}

public class child extends Parent {
public void childMethod(){
System.out.println("inside childMethod");
}

public static void main(String [] args){
Parent p =new Child();
p.childMethod();
}
}
```

Why cannot i call the child class method with following syntax?
Parent p =new Child();
p.childMethod();

The type of object that p holds is that of Child but still i cannot call child class method. Why such a call cannot complete in java?

Answer (score 2):

Because the *variable* is of type `Parent`.  Which means it can hold *any* object of type `Parent`, be it a `Child` or anything else that implements the `Parent` class.  The compiler can't guarantee that the variable will hold a `Child`, because you told it to make the variable a `Parent`.

To invoke a method on `Child`, make the variable that type:

```
Child p = new Child();
p.childMethod();
```

Alternatively, if you can yourself guarantee that the variable is pointing to a `Child` object, you can cast it:

```
Parent p = new Child();
Child c = (Child)p;
c.childMethod();
```

Though there's an argument to be made that if you can always guarantee that the variable will be a `Child` then it should have been of type `Child` in the first place.

Comment: I was drawing some parallel with static and dynamic binding. I thought that type of object will be determined at runtime which is of child type. is ti wrong to think that way?

Comment: @tin_tin: You can do a variety of tricks with polymorphism at runtime, but the compiler verifies things at compile-time.  Casting, checking types with `instanceof`, reflection, etc. can be used to change your types at runtime.  But be aware that trying to get around compile-time type checking means you're absolving the compiler of that responsibility and assuming that responsibility yourself.  It's useful, but should only be applied when really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call that method because `Parent#childMethod` is not a method. `Child#childMethod` is a method.

Think about this:

```
Parent p = new Parent();
p.childMethod();
```

Should you be able to do this? No, because you have an instance of `Parent`.

Your l-value is `Parent` so you will only be able to call methods that are defined in `Parent`. To do what you want, you'd need to cast `Parent` to a `Child`, but you need to make sure that it actually *is* an instance of `Child`:

```
if(p instanceof Child) {
  ((Child)p).childMethod()  
}
```

Comment: I was drawing some parallel with static and dynamic binding. I thought that type of object will be determined at runtime which is of child type. is ti wrong to think that way?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the reference variable type is of type Parent. Therefore, the variable only has access to the attributes and behaviors of the reference class. Note, you can override methods in the child class... For example:

```
public class child extends Parent {

  @Override
  public void parentMethod(){
    System.out.println("inside childMethod");
  }

  public static void main(String [] args){
    Parent p =new Child();
    p.childMethod(); // PRINTS "inside childMethod"
  }
}
```